# Driving TEC below rated voltage

Tags: driver, peltier, undervoltage

Can a TEC driving IC such as the MAX1979 rated for TEC voltages up to 6V be used to control a 12V TEC - can TEC work under their rated voltage, with the amount of heat moved controlled by current, or would the colling performance be greatly diminished at lower voltages?

Comment: Please don't use obscure TLAs without explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming TEC , Thermo Electric Cooling then yes you can, the performance is obviously affected, The datasheets often show this variation in performance. Performance is a function of voltage which controls the current just like a resistor. and the reverse is true.

Answer (score 2):

TEC performance is pretty good in low voltages due to lower ohmic losses. As rough approximation, TEC's heat transfer is proportional to its current, but ohmic self-heating is proportional to square of current, so at lower voltages TEC produces less own heat per unit of treansferred heat, so it is more effective at lower voltage.

Thus, it is better to drive TEC with variable voltage/current to control its power than use PWM.

But TECs have relatively high thermoconductivity, so in some circumstances smaller (and less powerful) TEC is preferred in order to reduce thermoconductivity losses.

Comment: What would be the problem with PWM? Can a TEC even "see" PWM frequencies (500kHz ~ 1 MHz)

Comment: There's no problems driving TEC with PWM, but its preformance is somewhat worse. I updated my answer to explain it more clear. I do not know about RF losses in TEC, but if you want to control it with MHz freqs, i advice you to add LC lowpass filter (its values should be suitable small) as in buck power converter.

Comment: Another (I think major) issue with driving a TEC with PWM is noise pickup. In general, you use a TEC when you want a very low noise/low leakage detector. Injecting amp-level PWM currents a few centimeters from such a detector seems a very iffy proposition.

Answer (score 0):

TEC-12706 has high efficency when curent is 3.5A,TEC-12706 has max rate when curent is 6A.Diffent TEC has diffient efficeny,I will do experiment to prove it.Use 40*40*40mm square Cu,and TEC-10A tec driver,10ohm 50W resistor,use max 30v 3a power supply heat resistor,then test the curve,x-axis is resistor power,y-axis is TEC power rate,the curve is very intresting.if you want the result,please leave your email below.

Comment: Please post the information you suggest as a component of your answer. Supplying the datasheet related to the specific part you mention would also be valuable.